# Does Landscape support user management?

Tags: users, landscape

Does Landscape support the following user management features?

- create user
- delete user
- change password for user with given username
- add user to group
- remove user from group
- set user login shell
- expire password

If so, is it possible to apply the change to all the linked computers in one go?  E.g. change the password for a user on all linked servers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it in "one go" for multiple systems you should write a script and send it with Landscape. The "user management" interface does not support multiple computers.

Answer (score 4):

Landscape lets you edit all of the above across multiple users *on the same system* - the two screenshots below should give you a good overview: first we select multiple users, then we edit them in a single pass.

[image: selecting multiple users]
[image: editing multiple users in one go]